# How do I center an avatar element that is within a cardHeader component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui for a frontend project and I have cards that display data. I want to display an avatar in the card in the center. I am using a card header to insert my avatar but am not able to center it. I tried setting alignContent and textAlign to center in the media style class but that doesn't helps.

What should I do to achieve that center alignment? Let me know if I should be using something other than the cardHeader.

```
<CardHeader
     className={classes.media}
     avatar={<Avatar alt="Alias" src={alias1} className={classes.small} />}
   />
```

Update: I got the result by specifying marginLeft and marginRight to be 'auto' in the "small" class. But the accepted answer also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CardHeader` is expecting a `title`, which is rendered with a `flex: 1 1 auto` style, regardless of whether you provide the `title` prop or not. That's what's stopping you from using `justifyContent` in your `media` class styles.

There are several ways to approach this, but if you don't make use of other `CardHeader` props, I would simply replace it with `Box` or `Grid`.

```js
const {Card, Box, Avatar, CardContent, Typography, makeStyles } = MaterialUI

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "#eeeeee",
    maxWidth: 400
  }
});

function MyCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" p={2}>
        <Avatar alt="Alias" className={classes.small} />
      </Box>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="body2">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit modi
          delectus laudantium neque perspiciatis voluptate aut aliquam tempore
          atque nobis.
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyCard />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
style={{ justifyContent: "center", display: "flex" }}
```